# What is the difference between "cerca del corazón" and "cerca al corazón"?

Tags: gramática, preposiciones, contracciones

Para traducir esta frase al español:

> We hold these traditions close to our heart.

¿Cuál de estas preposiciones usar: "al" o "del"?

What is the difference between "cerca del corazón" and "cerca al corazón"?

Comment: Me quedé preguntando por qué esto se veía un poco raro -- y luego me dí cuenta.  Normalmente se usaría *alma* y no *corazón*: "cerca del alma."

Answer (score 5):

Si consultamos el *Diccionario Panhispánico de Dudas*, obtenemos [lo siguiente](http://lema.rae.es/dpd/?key=cerca) (negritas mías):

> **cerca**. 1. Adverbio que significa ‘en lugar o tiempo próximos’. Normalmente se construye seguido de un complemento con *de* que expresa el término de referencia: *«Había pasado la infancia en un pueblo cerca de Málaga»* (Pitol *Juegos* [Méx. 1982]); *«Estamos cerca del final»* (*Nación* [C. Rica] 13.2.97). **No debe usarse, en estos casos, la preposición *a***: ⊗*«Custodiaban un coche cargado de explosivos cerca a una de las pistas»* (*Abc* [Esp.] 23.8.89).

Por tanto, el adverbio *cerca* va seguido siempre de la preposición *de*, y nunca de *a*.

---

Nota: ten en cuenta que las preposiciones son *a* o *de*, no *al* o *del*, que resultan de las contracciones *a + el* y *de + el*.

Answer (score 4):

First, *cerca al corazón* is wrong in Spanish. It means nothing. You don't use the preposition *a* with this kind of adverbs in Spanish.

In Spanish we have some adverbs that indicate position (locative adverbs) and can be used alone or with a reference. Examples are *cerca*, *lejos*, *encima*, *debajo*... If we use them without a reference, it is implicit. For instance:

> La tienda está cerca.

The shop is near. Near what? This is implicit; depending on the context, it may be near us, or near some other place we are talking about. In English, if you want to use a reference, you would use different propositions (or none), depending on the adverb (or adverbial phrase):

> The shop is near. --> The shop is near the fountain.
>
> The shop is close. --> The shoe is close *to* the fountain.
>
> The shop is far. --> The shop is far *from* the fountain.
>
> The green book is on top. --> The green book is on top *of* the pile.

In Spanish, the preposition to indicate space relation is *de*, and this is the one we use with location adverbs if we want to set a reference:

> La tienda está cerca. --> La tienda está cerca *de* la fuente.
>
> La tienda está lejos. --> La tienda está lejos *de* la fuente.
>
> El libro verde está encima. --> El libro verde está encima *de* la pila.

In your example, the only possibility is *Tenemos estas tradiciones cerca del corazón*. Whenever you want to set a reference for a locative adverb or adverbial phrase in Spanish, use the preposition *de*.

Comment: we can say in these cases the English "to" and "from" are totally opposites to their original meaning in spanish.